# Convert OPUS stream to PCM or RTP

Tags: voip, rtp, pcm, opus

Currently, I am developing a VOIP system. I can send the SIP stream to the mumble server, after converting the RTP stream to PCM and the voice quality is fine in mumble client. But, the Mumble stream (OPUS) to SIP is not working, always getting noise. I am converting the mumble channel's stream (OPUS) to RTP and sending it to the SIP client. Is there any library or source code to find out the RTP problem, that is not receiving by SIP?

**N.B: After converting The receiving stream into a .wav file, the voice quality is ok, but not working in the SIP client.**

**OPUS Decoded Code:**

```
public byte[] SendDecodeMumbleDataToMulticast(byte[] encodedData, int uid, int cid)
{
    var _decoder = new OpusDecoder(8000, 1) { EnableForwardErrorCorrection = true };
    if (encodedData == null)
    {
        //_decoder.Decode(null, 0, 0, new byte[_sampleRate / _frameSize], 0);
        return null;
    }

    int samples = OpusDecoder.GetSamples(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length, 8000);
    if (samples < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }

    byte[] dst = new byte[samples * sizeof(ushort)];
    int length = _decoder.Decode(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length, dst, 0);
    if (dst.Length != length)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref dst, length);
    }   


    RTPPacket rtp = ToRTPPacket(dst, 16, 1);
    OnRTPReceived?.Invoke(rtp);

    return dst;
}
```